# Regex to get a word if not wrapped by quotation

Tags: php, regex

If we have:

```
$text = 'Jame is sleeping but pretend that is "studying"';
```

Now i need a `regex` to get all words after `is` but if is not wrapped by double or single quotations.

the result should be just `sleeping` and not `studying`.

Comment: Is a quote on one side still valid? I threw this together /is [^"'].+?\b/

Comment: all words is not just sleeping. but `sleeping`, `but`, `pretend`, `that` and `is`.

Comment: I think he means all words that **immediately** follow an "is". OP you should make that clearer.

Comment: It might be easier to help if you provide some real-world examples and the results you want. Also please show [what you have tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is pretty simple actually:

```
is\s(\w+)
```

You can make it a bit more liberal:

```
is\s([^\s"']+)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
is (\w+)
```

**[Working example](http://regex101.com/r/bA4rA2)**